# Read and parse json file from workspace on slave node

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, json

I have a Jenkins job which runs on a slave node on another machine, both master and slave run on windows. The slave node is being run as a windows service. I am unable to read a json file from workspace in the slave node and parse it. The JSON file structure is like given below. I need to read the EmailProperties object and modify each of the properties and save the json file again. I have tried multiple suggestions on readFile() & readJSON(), but none  of them is working. Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

**JSON file:**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "EmailProperties": {
      "MailPort": "587",
      "MailServer": "mydomainmailserver.outlook.com",
      "Password": "password123$",
      "Sender": "company@domain.com"
    }
}
```

**Properties file:**

```
[transformation]
json_dev_EmailProperties.MailPort = 663
json_dev_EmailProperties.MailServer = devmailserver.outlook.com
json_dev_EmailProperties.Password = DevPassword123$
json_dev_EmailProperties.Sender = company@devmailserver.outlook.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the code that worked for me, if there is any other better way to do this, suggestions are most welcome.

**Main Method:**

```
def transformjsonfile(propertiesPath, jsonfilepath) {

  // Load Properties file 
  Properties props = new Properties()
  props.load(new StringReader(readFile(propertiesPath)))

  // Load json file
  def json = jsonParseFile(jsonfilepath)

  // Transform json
  json = transformValues(props, json)
  
  // Write back the tranformed config to the json file
  formatAndWriteBackJson(json)
}
```

**Helper methods:**

```
def jsonParseFile(def jsonfilepath) {
    def fileContent = readFile(file: jsonfilepath, encoding: "UTF-8")
    def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurperClassic()
    def data = jsonSlurper.parseText(fileContent.replaceAll("\\s", "").replaceAll("\uFEFF", ""))
    return data
}

def formatAndWriteBackJson(json)
{
  def jsonOut = new JsonBuilder(json).toPrettyString()
  writeFile file: jsonfilepath, text: jsonOut.toString()
}

def transformValues(props, json) {
  for (String name: props.keySet()) {
    String givenValue = props.getProperty(name);
    String value = givenValue.trim();
    if (name.startsWith("json_${env.Environment}_")) {
      splitarray = name.split("json_${env.Environment}_")
      jsonvalue = splitarray[1]
      key = "${jsonvalue}"
      transformvalue = "${value}"
      def someString = "${key}"
      def someChar = '.'
      int count = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < someString.length(); i++) {
        if (someString.charAt(i) == someChar) {
          count++;
        }
      }
      keyvalue = "json"
      splitarray = key.split('\\.')
      lab1: for (int j = 0; j <= count; j++) {
        keyvalue = keyvalue + "." + splitarray[j]
        jsonvalue = Eval.me('json', json, "${keyvalue}")
        if (jsonvalue == null) {
          break lab1;
        }
        if (jsonvalue != null) {
          println 'condition met'
          if (j == count) {
            Eval.me('json', json, "${keyvalue} ='$transformvalue'")
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return json
}
```